# mysql query for unicode characters

Tags: mysql

I have a query to check my column has  vertical tab (VT)
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000B/index.htm

In sql developer I use below.

```
SELECT name  FROM mytable where name like "%VT%";
```

I cannot run same in  mysql command line I tried

```
SELECT name  FROM mytable where name like "%\\u000b%";
```

How can I run  this query in command line ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer

```
SELECT name  FROM mytable where name like CONCAT("%",CHAR(11),"%");
```